# metatag_display_extender plugin does not exist

Tags: 8

I am migrating a Drupal site over, the following error is being received... I have clear cache, did a rebuild and no luck. Any suggestions

> **The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.**
>
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
> "metatag_display_extender" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for
> Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsPluginManager are: default in
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('metatag_display_extender')
> (Line: 16)
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('metatag_display_extender',
> Array) (Line: 83)
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('metatag_display_extender')
> (Line: 161)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->initDisplay(Object,
> Array) (Line: 91)
> Drupal\views\DisplayPluginCollection->initializePlugin('default')
> (Line: 38) Drupal\views\DisplayPluginCollection->__construct(Object,
> Object) (Line: 728) Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initDisplay() (Line:
> 1754) Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->access('page_1') (Line: 60)
> Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)

Comment: Hey acctman, please always try to include the steps that need to be performed to reproduce this issue. What exactly have you done before you ran into the error? How did you migrate? What did you migrate? `Any suggestions` is a too broad question and the only answer to it is: Debug! And then edit your question and add debugging info as well. Many thanks 

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to add `metatag_views` to an install profile.

I fixed this issue by adding a config dependency on `metatag_views` to the top of `views.settings.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - metatag_views
```

There's [more information on this Drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2927551#comment-13677219).